# In Python Selenium, all but first element in driver.find_elements have no innertext

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Python Selenium, using the following script:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
xpath_str = "//*[@class='texts']"
for e in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath_str):
    print(e.tag_name)
    print(e.text)
```

The first text element's HTML, I don't really know why it's like this either:

```
<p class="texts">
                                        1 :
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                            FIRST TEXT
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                    </p>
```

The second and third are also like this.

The second and third

elements are found but they don't contain any text.

The xpath string works fine on an xpath tester using driver.page_source printed just before the for-loop and all elements do contain the correct text.

What is wrong with the way I'm getting this text?

The output should be:

```
"p"
"1 : FIRST TEXT"
"p"
"2 : SECOND TEXT"
"p"
"3 : THIRD TEXT"
```

But I got:

```
"p"
"FT : FIRST TEXT"
"p"
""
"p"
""
```

Comment: add a `WebDriverWait`. also, try using `get_attribute('innerText')` instead of `.text`. like this `print(e.get_attribute('textContent').strip())`

Comment: Thank you @Obaskly get_attribute('innerText').strip() worked fine after using re.sub() to eliminate remaining tabs and newlines.